# How can I redirect to console and to file?

Tags: linux, centos5, tee

I am training redirect to console and to a file using this line:

```
yum install my_rpm | tee /tmp/test.log
```

But this line does not appear neither in console nor in the file:

```
Is this ok [y/N]:
```

Any idea?

Comment: Do you force close the program at the prompt? If so, it may be possible that the line was still in the buffer and not actually written yet.

Comment: Yes Colonel seems that one is the problem, I found the script command and works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Some programs detect whether stdout is a terminal (man isatty) and change their behavior accordingly. As `yum` can not know that what is written to the pipe ends up on the console, it might switch to non-interactive mode.